Why does my game lag while testing?
While I was testing my game yesterday, the fps started at 60 and dropped below. While testing my game today, my game, which normally starts at 60 fps, started with 2 fps. Thinking that the reason was due to the project, I opened my old projects and the same problem occurred there too. I wonder what's the problem? What causes this? If you look at the screenshot I sent, everything is on the ceiling in Profiler.


Try looking at the lower section of the profiler to find out what's taking so much time in each coloured block.

@DMGregory Thank you for your answer, I wrote the solution above. It had to be restarted. Instead of turning the PC off and on.

To share a solution, please post in the "Your Answer" below. Solutions always go in answer posts, never in the question post.

@DMGregory I did what you said

Thank you. After a short delay, you should be able to click the ✅ near the top-left of your answer to mark it as "Accepted", which signals to other folks struggling with similar issues that this solution was verified to work for you.

@DMGregory It says I have to wait 2 hours, then I press it. I thank you for your help.

I solved the problem with the screenshot I last posted in another forum. I was turning the computer off and on, but it didn't work. Restarting fixed it.

